# Select A%B from a column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table in my oracle Database.It has a column.Column has both A%B and A/B values in it.I just want to select values A%B.I wrote a solution like

```
SELECT name FROM Testcase WHERE 'A%B' like name;
```

it worked but it is not up to the mark.

Comment: define _but it is not up to the mark._

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm newbie on SO, but I don't understand why was this question down voted. I find it to be regular and quite interesting question. I'm voting up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your table is:

```
 create table ab (name varchar2(3));

 insert into ab values ('A%B');
 insert into ab values ('A/B');
```

In order to write query which returns only 'A%B', you need to set escape character to escape % which is used as wild card for one or more characters in LIKE statement.

```
 select name from ab where name like 'A/%B' escape '/';
```

This query returns only 'A%B'

Note that in your example LIKE statement works exactly like = . You need to add wild card in order to make LIKE useful in matching part of string, something like this

```
 select name from ab where name like 'A/%B%' escape '/';
```